# How to change text position on responsive page with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive

I hope you're doing good.

So, I have this problem here.
I want to create a page layout something like this:

```
Image - Description
Description - Image
Image - Description
and so on...
```

And whenever it viewed on smaller device, it turn to:

```
Image
Description

Image
Description

and so on...
```

But instead, I got this:

```
Image
Description

Description
Image 

Image
Description
```

How do I achieve that layout?

Here's my code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid padding">

  <div class="container padding">
    <div class="row padding">
      <div class="col-md-6 mt-5 mb-5">
        <img class="img-fluid rounded border" width="300" height="200" src="" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center mt-5 mb-5">
        <h3>Text Heading</h3>
        <p class="lead">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Just A Regular Text</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center mt-5 mb-5">
        <h3>Text Heading</h3>
        <p class="lead">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Just A Regular Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 mt-5 mb-5">
        <img class="img-fluid rounded border" width="300" height="200" src="" alt="" />
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 mt-5 mb-5">
        <img class="img-fluid rounded border" width="300" height="200" src="" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center mt-5 mb-5">
        <h3>Text Heading</h3>
        <p class="lead">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Just A Regular Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define each row separately (you have all your columns in one row), and then in each row, define each block as col-12 to start and switch to col-md-6 for larger displays.

Put everything in image / description order to start, and for the alternating row, at Bootstrap’s order-md-first to the text block to have that appear first.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row padding">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mt-5 mb-5">
            <img class="img-fluid rounded border" width="300" height="200" src="" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 align-self-center mt-5 mb-5">
            <h3>Text Heading</h3>
            <p class="lead">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Just A Regular Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mt-5 mb-5">
            <img class="img-fluid rounded border" width="300" height="200" src="" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 align-self-center mt-5 mb-5 order-md-first">
            <h3>Text Heading</h3>
            <p class="lead">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Just A Regular Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row padding">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mt-5 mb-5">
            <img class="img-fluid rounded border" width="300" height="200" src="" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 align-self-center mt-5 mb-5">
            <h3>Text Heading</h3>
            <p class="lead">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Just A Regular Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Make a row for each col, that make sense. Oh, I didn't knew about `order-md-first` things. Well, you're helping me out, so thanks mate!